# time of daily maximum

Tags: r, time

I have a time series dataset for temperature and other parameters
I am using the apply.daily function to extract daily maximum temperatures

```
DailyMaxAirTemp <- apply.daily(xx_select1$Temp_C, max,na.rm=TRUE)
```

xx_select is a .xts object

```
                    Temp_C   
2015-07-01 00:00:00 " 11.977"
2015-07-01 00:10:00 " 11.880"   
2015-07-01 00:20:00 " 11.589"
```

DailyMaxAirTemp returns:

```
DailyMaxAirTemp
                    Temp_C   
2015-07-01 23:55:00 " 26.598"
2015-07-02 23:55:00 " 27.063"
2015-07-03 23:55:00 " 29.015"
2015-07-04 23:55:00 " 30.091"
2015-07-05 23:55:00 " 31.996"
2015-07-06 23:55:00 " 29.115"
....
```

but I would also like to get the time associated with the maximums so I could know the average time at which the peak temperature occurs instead of "23:55:00" for each day
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why `Temp_C` are characters?

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward to get the time of day associated with each maximum temperature. Using the `xts` object you defined above,

```
# max temp for each day
Tmax <- apply.daily(xx_select1$Temp_C[,1], max, na.rm=TRUE)
# time of day of max temp
timeTmax <- index(xx_select1$Temp_C)[xx_select1$Temp_C[,1] %in% Tmax]
```

I think the best way to solve your average time-of-day problem is via the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
# make all dates the same
times <- update(timeTmax, year=2000, month=1, mday=1)
# mean time of day for max temp
format(mean(times), format="%H:%M:%S")
```